# data exist on my DB but PHP returns NULL

Tags: php, sql, encoding, utf-8

I have a weird problem for some of my rows in a specific column.

The column is named description and there are a number of entries.

When performing a query from php, I can get all of them except one (php return NULL).

In my phpmyAdmin the data for that specific is this:

```
Î¼Î±Î»Î»Î¿Î½ Î¸Î± Ï€ÏÎµÏ€ÎµÎ¹ Î½Î± ÎºÎ±Î½Î¿Ï…Î¼Îµ Ï…Ï€Î¿Î¼Î¿Î½Î· Î¼ÎµÏ‡ÏÎ¹ Ï„Î· Î´ÎµÏ…Ï„ÎµÏÎ± Ï€Î
```

and the structure for that column is : `varchar(200), utf-general-ci`

I know that this entry is Greek. But there are other Greek entries, which are visible.

My php code is this:

for quering:

```
$query="SELECT description,date FROM allComments p JOIN  login l ON (p.IdUser=l.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto=$photo";
```

and for inserting data:

```
$query2="INSERT INTO allComments (IdPhoto,IdUser,description,dates) VALUES($photoId,$id,'$text','$date')";
```

What do you think might be the problem?

The entry is made correctly, since all the other columns (date for example are retrieved correctly - only this column is null)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Encoding in mysqli.

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

[PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli_set_charset)